# what does deviceready event in cordova really do

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When we creating a watcher in cordova, we need to fire it after the device is ready.

In ionic framework we are using the following code to do that.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $cordovaPlugin.someFunction().then(success, error);
});
```

I want to know what this code exactly doing..? What is `someFunction()` and what is done with `.then(success, error);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question which could simply be answered by the existing cordova documentation:

[Cordova Documentation - DeviceReady Event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)

I would also recommend you to read some tutorials or guides on how to start with hybrid app development.

`success()` will get called, when the device has fired the `device ready` event.
`error`should be self-explaining.

Comment: What is the meaning of `$cordovaPlugin.someFunction()`..?

Comment: That is just an example for a plugin which gets called when the device enters the device ready state.